# Hide Arrow icon in selectize.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I'm using the selectize.js package in my application (https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js) and i'm trying to hide the cursor.

[image]

Bellow is a code as example:

```js
 $('#select-beast-single-disabled').selectize({
                    create: true,
                    sortField: {field: 'text'}
                });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/js/standalone/selectize.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/css/selectize.css" />
        <div class="demo">
            <div class="control-group">
                <select id="select-beast-single-disabled" class="demo-default" placeholder="Select a person...">
                    <option value="">Select a person...</option>
                    <option value="1">Arnold</option>
                    <option value="2" selected>Nikola Tesla</option>
                </select>
            </div>

        </div>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Is there any workaround for it? Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 2):

I believe [this](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/issues/587) solves your problem

therefore, two possibilities:

> - Set the option maxItems with '1' as a string, in order to skip the condition which insert a different css class in the input.

like this:

```js
  $('#select-beast-single-disabled').selectize({
                    create: true,
                    sortField: {field: 'text'},
                    maxItems: '1'
                });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/js/standalone/selectize.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/css/selectize.css" />
        <div class="demo">
            <div class="control-group">
                <select id="select-beast-single-disabled" class="demo-default" placeholder="Select a person...">
                    <option value="">Select a person...</option>
                    <option value="1">Arnold</option>
                    <option value="2" selected>Nikola Tesla</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

> - Remove the arrow from the css.

like this:

```js
 $('#select-beast-single-disabled').selectize({
                    create: true,
                    sortField: {field: 'text'}
                });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/js/standalone/selectize.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/css/selectize.css" />
        <div class="demo">
            <div class="control-group">
                <select id="select-beast-single-disabled" class="demo-default" placeholder="Select a person...">
                    <option value="">Select a person...</option>
                    <option value="1">Arnold</option>
                    <option value="2" selected>Nikola Tesla</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
  <style>
    .selectize-control.single .selectize-input:after{
      display:none;
    }
  </style>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @ i.signori, but if I use the last answer, I will remove the arrow icon from all selected objects. The first answer also brings some style questions, but it's promising!